# Replace after searched string with a variable (containing slashes) in sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

#### Tools

- `rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.31`
- `GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- `GNU Awk 5.3.0`
- `sed (GNU sed) 4.9`
- `tr (GNU coreutils) 9.4`

#### Attempted behaviour

- Grab the first 9 colours from `~/.colour_list` which has the colours printed with a newline between each one
- Remove the leading `#` from each colour
- Place a `/` every 2nd character; `FF/FF/FF/`
- Append each colour with a transparency value; `FF/FF/FF/2F`
- Prepend each colour with the string `rgba:`; `rgba: FF/FF/FF/2F`
- Place a `,` every 16 characters (except for the last character) to create a comma separated list; `rgba: FF/FF/FF/2F, rgba: 2F/AA/66/2F ...`
- Place this entire comma separated list into a variable `bc`
- Place the variable `bc` after the exact string match `bar_color               =`  (including spaces) in the file `test.conf`

#### Input

`.colour_list`;

```
#000000
#000001
#000002
#000004
#000005
#000006
#000007
#000008
#000009
#00000A
#00000B
#00000C
#00000D
#00000E
#00000F
```

#### Process (script)

`tst.sh`;

```bash
#!/bin/bash

value=9
transparency=FF

bc=$(head -n${value} ~/.colour_list | 
    tr -d '#' | 
    sed 's/.\{2\}/&\//g;s/.$//' | 
    awk '{print "rgba:" $0 transparency}' transparency=$transparency | 
    sed 's/.\{16\}/&,/g')

sed -ri "s|^(bar_colour             \s*=\s*).*|\1$bc|" ~/test.conf

echo $bc
```

#### Output

**Output**:

`bash` output;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unterminated `s' command
rgba:00/00/00/FF rgba:00/00/01/FF rgba:00/00/02/FF rgba:00/00/04/FF rgba:00/00/05/FF rgba:00/00/06/FF rgba:00/00/07/FF rgba:00/00/08/FF rgba:00/00/09/FF
```

`~/test.conf` **not** changed;

```
...
bar_colour              = test
...
```

**Expected output**:

`bash` output;

```
rgba:00/00/00/FF, rgba:00/00/01/FF, rgba:00/00/02/FF, rgba:00/00/04/FF, rgba:00/00/05/FF, rgba:00/00/06/FF, rgba:00/00/07/FF, rgba:00/00/08/FF, rgba:00/00/09/FF
```

`~/test.conf` changed;

```
...
bar_colour              = rgba:00/00/00/FF, rgba:00/00/01/FF, rgba:00/00/02/FF, rgba:00/00/04/FF, rgba:00/00/05/FF, rgba:00/00/06/FF, rgba:00/00/07/FF, rgba:00/00/08/FF, rgba:00/00/09/FF
...
```

#### Issues

I have two issues.

1. The `$bc` assignment (see `sed 's/.\{2\}/&\//g;s/.$//'`) removes all commas, where I would only like to remove the final comma (i.e. the final character) of the entire string. Please note, I do require the `$bc` assignment (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037232/replace-after-searched-string-with-a-variable-containing-slashes-in-sed-awk/78041621?noredirect=1#comment137589419_78041621)).
2. Upon finding the string, `colour             =` , I want to place the value of `$bc` after it but I instead get an error (see above). Please note that I would like to retain the gap between `colour` and `=`, which is a mixture of tabs and spaces.

#### Methods tried

I have tried previous answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584926/5414155), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23134318/5414155), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806880), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806540)) but none of them seem to work and invariably return as above.

I am guessing for the `awk` error at least, this is because the variable I am trying to replace with contains slashes, but I am not sure why `sed` is throwing an error. I require the slashes as the expected format is as per [XQueryColor](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XParseColor.3.html#sect4) specifications.

I have placed the script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/#). Apart from suggesting `$bc` be wrapped in double quotes at the final line (which is not necessary for the script's functioning), it reports `No issues detected!`.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Changed script to the following, as per the comments;

```bash
value=9
transparency=FF

bc=$(head -n${value} ~/.colour_list | 
    tr -d '#' | 
    sed 's@.\{2\}@&\/@g;s@.$@@' | 
    awk '{print "rgba:" $0 transparency}' transparency=$transparency | 
    sed 's@.\{16\}@&,@g')

sed -ri "s|^(bar_colour             \s*=\s*).*|\1$bc|" ~/test.conf

echo $bc
```

This also provided the same errors as per the Output section, unfortunately.

Comment: Show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuénot Apologies. That has now been added.

Comment: Off-topic: In `bc=$(head xxx | tr xxx | sed xxx | awk xxx)` you can insert an Enter after each `|`, so you can read the whole command without horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thank you @WalterA, that has now been edited.

Comment: (when using multi-line commands, I would indent all except the first)
You can also replace the backtics with `bc=$(command)`

Comment: `awk '{print "rgba:" $0 transparency}' transparency=$transparency` is not working. Try something like `awk -v transparency="$transparency" '{print "rgba:" $0 transparency}'`

Comment: Thank you also @GillesQuénot. I attempted what you suggested, I think. I have included this in an edit to the main post.

Comment: Thanks again @WalterA. I have altered the scripts accordingly. I am not sure if we have a different version of awk, but that command does work for me. In other words, it matches the expected output of `rgba:FF/FF/FF/FF, `. Though it prints `rgba:FF/FF/FFFF` (note the lack of final `/`) with `s/.$//` from the `sed` line above; removing `s/.$//` returns the expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256949/discussion-between-walter-a-and-twelfth).

Comment: please update the question to provide the sample input that's supposed to generate the expected output

Comment: you've added an EDIT and then stated the code *`This also did not work`* ... please describe what you mean by *`did not work`* ... error? wrong answer? something else?

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, thank you. I have specified what did not work. As for the input, that is the shell script, run from the terminal.

Comment: it looks like the input is coming from a file named `.colour_list` so I'm looking for the lines from `.colour_list`

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, my apologies. I have now added that to the post.

Comment: I'm asking for the input data that generates your expected output; how exactly do you go from `#000000` to `rgba:21/1c/3b/FF`

Comment: @markp-fuso That is the script itself, pasted in the body of the post. Precisely, it is just above the section labelled 'Output and expected output'.

Comment: the script reads from `.colour_list` and generates strings like `rgba:21/1c/3b/FF`; there is nothing in your script that would allow you to take `#000000` as input and generate `rgba:21/1c/3b/FF` as output .... *unless* the row from `.colour_list` actually looks something like `#211c3b`, yes?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes. It takes the format I have pasted it in the post (as stated; that was an example file but the file is essentially plain text with a list of colours in hexadecimal, separated by newlines). There is nothing else besides those hexadecimal numbers. I will change the output so that everything is uniform.

Comment: @markp-fuso As I have stated, it is an example file. I am more concerned with the formatting, not getting something like `#00000F` to `rgba:21/1d/3b/FF`, apologies if that is not clear. The point is that the script would take whatever colours are in the given file `.colour_list` and, following processing via the script, output them in the format `rgba:xx/xx/xx/FF`. Either way, the output and expected output have been modified.

Comment: @markp-fuso I do not insist on it. Rather than extract and reformat irrelevant hexadecimal numbers from this post (as I could no longer access the original input; its contents change every few minutes), I quickly wrote a simple sample replacement to communicate the generalisable case.

Comment: We need you to provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste to reproduce your issue and test a potential solution with. Quickly writing something general that we can't use for that purpose because the expected output can't be produced from the sample input just makes it much harder for us to help you and the harder it is to help you the fewer people will have the time to do so and the less likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: Please do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs, "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here." and then [edit] your question to show the corrected script if you still have a problem. There's no point having people waste their time looking at a script that contains errors that shellcheck could detect and which might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, just to let you know, I have now reformatted the question so that it hopefully aligns better with the standards expected of a question and is easier to reproduce for anyone wishing to answer. I shall keep this in mind going forward for any future questions I may have on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat test.conf
...
bar_colour             = foo
bar_colour              = test
bar_colour               = bar
...
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

awk '
    NR == FNR {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        bc = bc sprintf("%srgba: %s/2F", (NR>1 ? ", " : ""), $0)
        if ( NR == 9 ) {
            nextfile
        }
        next
    }
    match($0,/^bar_colour              = /) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RLENGTH) bc
    }
    { print }
' .colour_list test.conf > "$tmp" &&
mv "$tmp" test.conf
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat test.conf
...
bar_colour             = foo
bar_colour              = rgba: 00/00/00/2F, rgba: 00/00/01/2F, rgba: 00/00/02/2F, rgba: 00/00/04/2F, rgba: 00/00/05/2F, rgba: 00/00/06/2F, rgba: 00/00/07/2F, rgba: 00/00/08/2F, rgba: 00/00/09/2F
bar_colour               = bar
...
```

---

How we got there...

Stepping through your "Attempted behaviour" list one at a time:

Grab the first 9 colours from ~/.colour_list which has the colours printed with a newline between each one

```
awk '
    { print }
    NR == 9 { exit }
' .colour_list
#000000
#000001
#000002
#000004
#000005
#000006
#000007
#000008
#000009
```

Remove the leading # from each colour

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        print
    }
    NR == 9 { exit }
' .colour_list
000000
000001
000002
000004
000005
000006
000007
000008
000009
```

Place a / every 2nd character; FF/FF/FF/

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        print
    }
    NR == 9 { exit }
' .colour_list
00/00/00
00/00/01
00/00/02
00/00/04
00/00/05
00/00/06
00/00/07
00/00/08
00/00/09
```

Append each colour with a transparency value; FF/FF/FF/2F

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        print $0 "/2F"
    }
    NR == 9 { exit }
' .colour_list
00/00/00/2F
00/00/01/2F
00/00/02/2F
00/00/04/2F
00/00/05/2F
00/00/06/2F
00/00/07/2F
00/00/08/2F
00/00/09/2F
```

Prepend each colour with the string rgba:; rgba: FF/FF/FF/2F

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        print "rgba:", $0 "/2F"
    }
    NR == 9 { exit }
' .colour_list
rgba: 00/00/00/2F
rgba: 00/00/01/2F
rgba: 00/00/02/2F
rgba: 00/00/04/2F
rgba: 00/00/05/2F
rgba: 00/00/06/2F
rgba: 00/00/07/2F
rgba: 00/00/08/2F
rgba: 00/00/09/2F
```

Place a , every 16 characters (except for the last character) to create a comma separated list; rgba: FF/FF/FF/2F, rgba: 2F/AA/66/2F ...

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        printf "%srgba: %s/2F", (NR>1 ? ", " : ""), $0
    }
    NR == 9 { print ""; exit }
' .colour_list
rgba: 00/00/00/2F, rgba: 00/00/01/2F, rgba: 00/00/02/2F, rgba: 00/00/04/2F, rgba: 00/00/05/2F, rgba: 00/00/06/2F, rgba: 00/00/07/2F, rgba: 00/00/08/2F, rgba: 00/00/09/2F
```

Place this entire comma separated list into a variable bc

```
bc=$( awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        printf "%srgba: %s/2F", (NR>1 ? ", " : ""), $0
    }
    NR == 9 { print ""; exit }
' .colour_list )
```

Place the variable bc after the exact string match bar_color               = (including spaces) in the file test.conf

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bc=$( awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        printf "%srgba: %s/2F", (NR>1 ? ", " : ""), $0
    }
    NR == 9 { print ""; exit }
' .colour_list )
printf 'bar_colour              = %s\n' "$bc" > test.conf

cat test.conf
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
bar_colour              = rgba: 00/00/00/2F, rgba: 00/00/01/2F, rgba: 00/00/02/2F, rgba: 00/00/04/2F, rgba: 00/00/05/2F, rgba: 00/00/06/2F, rgba: 00/00/07/2F, rgba: 00/00/08/2F, rgba: 00/00/09/2F
```

It's not clear why you want a shell variable `bc` or to format the output for `test.conf` outside of awk instead of just:

```
awk '
    {
        sub(/^#/,"")
        gsub(/../,"&/"); sub("/$","")
        bc = bc sprintf("%srgba: %s/2F", (NR>1 ? ", " : ""), $0)
    }
    NR == 9 {
        printf "bar_colour              = %s\n", bc
        exit
    }
' .colour_list > test.conf
```

```
$ cat test.conf
bar_colour              = rgba: 00/00/00/2F, rgba: 00/00/01/2F, rgba: 00/00/02/2F, rgba: 00/00/04/2F, rgba: 00/00/05/2F, rgba: 00/00/06/2F, rgba: 00/00/07/2F, rgba: 00/00/08/2F, rgba: 00/00/09/2F
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I required the variable as there was a potential future use case whereby I would 1) pass the variable into 2 fields within `test.conf` (instead of just `bar_colour`) and 2) change the alpha value or `transparency` value for at least one of the 2 fields, and for these values to be distinct; `FF/FF/FF/2F` and `FF/FF/FF/FF`, for instance. As this was ancillary to my primary purpose, I thought it best to refrain from including this additional complexity.

Comment: Good decision. If you can't figure out how to do whatever you want to do **within that 1 call to awk** then you can always ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Once you bring `awk` into the mix there's probably a good chance you can replace other string manipulation tools (eg, `head`, `tr`, `sed`).

For some reason OP doesn't want to provide the actual contents of `.colour_list` so I'm *guessing* the contents look something like:

```
$ cat .colour_list
#211c3b
#CB6875
#6E5A86
#745A84
#895B83
#8F668B
#AC6884
#d8abb7
#977780
#ignore_this_line
```

One `awk` idea that generates the expected output:

```
value=9
transparency=FF

awk -v cnt="${value}" -v tp="${transparency}" '
FNR <= cnt { raw=substr($0,2,6)
             gsub(/../,"&/",raw)
             printf "%srgba:%sFF", (FNR==1 ? "" : ", "), raw
           }
END        { print "" }
' .colour_list
```

This generates:

```
rgba:21/1c/3b/FF, rgba:CB/68/75/FF, rgba:6E/5A/86/FF, rgba:74/5A/84/FF, rgba:89/5B/83/FF, rgba:8F/66/8B/FF, rgba:AC/68/84/FF, rgba:d8/ab/b7/FF, rgba:97/77/80/FF
```

Capturing in `bash` variable `bc`:

```
$ bc=$(    awk -v cnt="${value}" -v tp="${transparency}" '
FNR <= cnt { raw=substr($0,2,6)
             gsub(/../,"&/",raw)
             printf "%srgba:%sFF", (FNR==1 ? "" : ", "), raw
           }
END        { print "" }
' .colour_list)

$ typeset -p bc
declare -- bc="rgba:21/1c/3b/FF, rgba:CB/68/75/FF, rgba:6E/5A/86/FF, rgba:74/5A/84/FF, rgba:89/5B/83/FF, rgba:8F/66/8B/FF, rgba:AC/68/84/FF, rgba:d8/ab/b7/FF, rgba:97/77/80/FF"
```

---

As for the replacement of `test` in `.test.conf` ...

We'll add a couple lines to show we're only modifying the desired line:

```
$ cat .test.conf
line one        = some stuff
bar_colour      = test
line three      = some stuff
```

Since we know `${bc}` contains forward slashes we'll want to use some other character as the delimiter in our `sed` sccript; I've opted for `|`:

```
$ sed -E "s|(bar_colour[[:space:]]+= )|\1${bc}|" .test.conf
line one        = some stuff
bar_colour      = rgba:21/1c/3b/FF, rgba:CB/68/75/FF, rgba:6E/5A/86/FF, rgba:74/5A/84/FF, rgba:89/5B/83/FF, rgba:8F/66/8B/FF, rgba:AC/68/84/FF, rgba:d8/ab/b7/FF, rgba:97/77/80/FFtest
line three      = some stuff
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable support for extended regexes
- `(bar_color[[:space:]]+= )` - (first) capture group; it's not clear from OP's description if there are spaces and/or tabs between `bar_colour` and `=` so `[[:space:]]+` should match both
- `\1"${bc}"` - insert contents of first capture group followed by contents of `bash` variable `bc`

Once OP is satisified with the result they can add `-i` to have `sed` perform an inplace update of `.test.conf`

---

I'm assuming OP has a follow-on need for `bc` otherwise the `sed` script could be pulled into the `awk` script (which would negate the need for variable `bc).

Answer (score 1):

My somewhat kludgy `awk`:

```bash
t=$(mktemp)
awk '
  NR==FNR && NR<= 9 { gsub(/[0-9A-F]{2}/,"&/"); sub(/$/,"2F, "); sub(/^#/,"rgba: "); out=out$0; next; }
  NR==FNR && NR==10 { $0=out; sub(/, *$/,""); out=$0; nextfile; }
  /colour {13,}=/{ sub(/=.*/,"= "out); }
  NR>10 { print }
' ~/.colour_list ~/test.conf >$t && mv $t ~/test.conf # check your permissions
```

As a general practice, please don't chain regex engines unless there's a really good reason one instance can't handle all the work. If you find yourself building a pipeline that includes `awk` AND `sed` AND `grep` AND `perl`, or any similar conglomeration of such, rethink your design (though admittedly, with this small a dataset it doesn't matter so much.)

---

As an aside and a thought experiment, mostly for the fun of it... depending on how big your files are, you can accomplish practically *all* this in native `bash`. It's admittedly an odd way to do it, but can be surprisingly efficient sometimes.

```bash
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash
 cat ~/test.conf
 echo =======
 nl=$'\n'
 shopt -s extglob patsub_replacement # turn on extended globs and '&' in patsubs
 c="$(<~/.colour_list)"              # load the color file
 c="${c:0:63}"                       # keep 9 lines (assumes fixed 7 byte format)
 c="${c//[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]/&/}"       # add / after every 2 hex digits
 c="${c//$'\n'/2F, }2F"              # newlines->"2F, ", add 2F at end
 c="${c//#/rgba: }"                  # hashes->"rgba: "

 t="$(<~/test.conf)"                           # load the conf file
 tmp="${t/#*colour             *([ ])=*([ ])}" # part to chop OFF the end
 head="${t%$tmp}"                              # Part to KEEP from the front
 tail="${tmp#*$'\n'}"                          # part to KEEP from the end
 echo "$head$c$nl$tail" > ~/test.conf          # update the file
 cat ~/test.conf

$: ./tst
foo
bar_colour              = test
bar
=======
foo
bar_colour              = rgba: 00/00/00/2F, rgba: 00/00/01/2F, rgba: 00/00/02/2F, rgba: 00/00/04/2F, rgba: 00/00/05/2F, rgba: 00/00/06/2F, rgba: 00/00/07/2F, rgba: 00/00/08/2F
bar
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I appreciate also the general advice with respect to chaining and shall test the native `bash` soon. Thanks again.