# how to trim the first n chars and the last m from a file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with the content as below:

input.txt

```
export k="v"
```

`v` might include chars such as `\n` (an embedded newline).

The goal is to store `v` (without the enclosing double quotes) in a file named the same as the variable (in this case, `k`).

For example, I might have something like this -

```
export a_a="foooo
barrrrr"
```

which should store

```
foooo
barrrrr
```

in a file named `a_a`.

**Note that it can be multiline - and I don't have much control over input.**

I first get the key length as below

```
key=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
key_size= echo $key | wc -c
echo key_size
trim_size=$(( $key_size + 9 ))
value=$(cat "$filename" | cut -c $trim_size- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)
echo -n "$value"> $key
```

I am expecting this

```
foooo
barrrrr
```

But I get

```
foooo
```

The problem should be somewhere here `value=$(cat "$filename" | cut -c $trim_size- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)`
I want this line to treat embedded newline `\n` characters as part of the data.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The appearance of quotes suggests some sort of encoding. Which one is it? E.g. how would `k="v"` be represented if `v` contained `"` itself? Once you know the encoding, you can use a decoder to process the character stream that comes after `k=` (i.e. including the outer quotes, as they'd be part of the encoding).

Comment: `rev` operates by lines. Also, the `key_size=` line seems wrong.

Comment: this line is fine `key=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)` - it works as expected

Comment: I dont care if v has ". I just want to remove the last " and remove `export k="` from the beginign

Comment: @Amin That wasn't the point. The point was to include the general aspects of an encoding to give you a robust solution. But you can, of course, not care about your solution's robustness.

Comment: I care about it actually. But I dont clearly understand the concern

Comment: but I something that works. the whole team waiting for me with this small issue

Comment: Your title says `sh` but your only tag is `bash`. Do you need specifically one or the other?

Comment: fixed - and I am also working on sed. I dont know if that works or not

Comment: You should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about.

Comment: If you can't just source input.txt and print the variable then [edit] your question to state why not and include supporting values in your sample input/output.

Comment: You say "The goal is to store v (without double quotes **in a file named output.txt**)" but then you write `echo -n "$value"> $key`. Which is it?

Comment: Ed - I think the varname is different in each file, so you'd have to parse it to know what to print... Sounds more and more like an [X/Y](http://xyproblem.info/) issue though, eh?

Comment: @PaulHodges the goal is to store it in file named $key

Comment: `key_size= echo $key | wc -c` doesn't make sense.  You probably meant `key_size=${#key}` (which works with `bash` and `sh`).  If you ran [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) you would find that it makes this suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to parse the file, just source it and use the variable (in a subshell):

```
$ cat input.txt
export a_a="foooo
barrrrr"
```

```
$ ( . input.txt; echo "$a_a"; ) > output.txt
```

```
$ cat output.txt
foooo
barrrrr
```

The above assumes you're in control of the contents of `input.txt` so you know its safe to source.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell:

```
tmpvar=$(cat input.txt)

key=${tmpvar%%=*}
key=${key#export }

value=${tmpvar#*\"}
value=${value%\"*}
```

bash:

```
[[ $(<input.txt) =~ "export "([^=]+)=\"(.*)\" ]]

key=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I dont care if v has ". I just want to remove the last " and remove export k=" from the beginign

```bash
$ cat input.txt 
export a_a="foooo
barrrrr"

$ sed '1s/^export .*="//;$s/"\s*$//' input.txt
foooo
barrrrr
```

Comment: I tested and it works. does it work if I have \\ // and some other  special characters as well?

Comment: does it work in sh as well?

Comment: you did not print it to a file named $key

Comment: Re "does it work for special characters as well": That's where you might meet the [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074941#comment137639866_78074941). Re "does it work in sh as well?": This uses `sed`, regardless whether you run it in `sh` or `bash`. Re "you did not print it to a file": If you are satisfied with the results printed on screen, just redirect the output to a file using  `>` (still regardless whether you use `sh` or `bash` -- although I thought you [opted for bash](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78074941/revisions) on this matter).

Comment: I want to handle cert files. there is no special character in cert file. is it?

Answer (score 0):

Since [jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78075210/8656552) got a better version of my answer in place a few minutes before I did, here's an `awk` solution.

```
$: cat input.txt
# this works with trash in the file before and behind,
... as long as it there are no equals or double-quotes.

export a_a="foooo\"and
barrrrr"

See? :)

$: awk -v RS='' -v FS="$'\000'" '{ print gensub(/^[^=]+="(.*)".*/,"\\1",1) > gensub(/^[^=]* +([^=]+)=.*/,"\\1",1) }' input.txt
$: cat a_a
foooo\"and
barrrrr
```

## Original Answer -

This is not doing what you think.

```
$: filename=input.txt
$: cat $filename
export a_a="foooo
barrrrr"
$: cat $filename | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
a_a
barrrrr"
$: key=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
$: echo "$key"
a_a
barrrrr"
```

`cut` is reading each *line* of the file. What you want to do is (apparently) parse the file as a single string and manipulate it accordingly.

[`bash` parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) can handle this.

```
$: content=$(< "$filename")
$: varname="${content#* }"; varname="${varname%%=*}"
$: value="${content#*=\"}"; value="${value%\"}"
$: echo "$value" > "$varname"
$: cat "$varname"
foooo
barrrrr
```

This is also quite fast.

Comment: This doesn't account for possible blank lines or any other content (though it could; c.f. [this more complex example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78044663/8656552).)

Comment: For your information, it's written ___[cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.)___ (and **not** _c.f._)

Comment: um... Thanks? I actually appreciate the correction, but *wow* that sounds "mansplainy", lol

Comment: It's funny how how "FYI" sounds helpfully informative but spelling it out "For your information" sounds condescending :-). Or maybe that should be F.Y.I. .....

Comment: I thought the same! Text is hard, lol... Either way, I've apparently been doing this wrong for *years*, so I'm glad to have it noted so I can stop doing that.

Comment: I've never used `cf.` myself but just googled it and apparently almost everyone uses it incorrectly. It's short for the Latin `conferre` which means `compare` and so it should only be used when drawing a comparison between 2 things, e.g. when discussing citric vs non-citric fruits you might say `cf. oranges, bananas`, but if you were just discussing citric fruits then you might say `e.g. oranges`. So apparently in the context of your first comment that should have been an `e.g.` instead of a `cf.`. TIL...

Comment: See [friends-dont-let-friends-use-cf](https://scientistseessquirrel.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/friends-dont-let-friends-use-cf/).

Comment: The standard, *correct* use is basically what I did. "It *doesn't*...though it *could*" *(compare what I did **here** with what's at that link, over **there**)*. I will admit that it's a little academic-pompous sounding, but that's sadly accurate to my personality, so long as you read it with (possibly excessive) cheer and enthusiasm. :)  I just got into the admittedly bad habit of sticking a period into the middle in the model of *i.e.* (**id est**, though in my head I always inaccurately use *in exempli*, which generally applies to how it's used) and *e.g.* (**exempli gratia**).

Comment: Ed - "TIL"? Also, my *other* major was Classical Studies. I always tell people my CIS/Classical BA was a study in "CoBOL, ForTran, Latin, (koine)Greek... all those ancient languages that people say are dead but other people are still using," lol